Why am I having issues executing a simple buffer overflow using the Seed Labs VM on an ARM machine?
I'm working through the buffer overflow lab on the seed VM . I have an M1 chip, which makes this a bit tricky. On Task 2, I'm trying to overwrite foo's return address with my shellcode. This is done by creating a "badfile" that is sent to another IP address (another VM) in the seed lab. I figured I could do this by overwriting foo's stack frame address with the address for my buffer in my badcode, but I'm having issues getting this to work. Here is my code so far. This is a python program that writes the badcode sent to the VM:
part 1.
part two
Here are the hints that the seed lab gave me about the frame pointers: Hints
And here is what the foo bof files look like.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/* Changing this size will change the layout of the stack.
* Instructors can change this value each year, so students
* won’t be able to use the solutions from the past. */
#ifndef BUF_SIZE
#define BUF_SIZE 160
#endif
int bof(char *str)
{
char buffer[160];
/* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
memcpy(buffer, str, 517);
return 1;
}
void foo(char *str)
{
...
bof(str);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char str[517];
int length = fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, stdin);
foo(str);
fprintf(stdout, "==== Returned Properly ====\n");
return 1;
}

I tried overwriting foo's stack frame address with the address for my buffer in my badcode, but I'm having issues getting this to work. I expected that in the attacked seed vm, I would see a message saying that the attack succeeded.
